# Is it okay to perform Dagger 2 injection inside a constructor of an Activity

Tags: android, dagger-2

The examples online regarding `Dagger2` for `Android` always perform dependency injection inside the `onCreate` function.

Why not do it inside the constructor of the `Activity`? It's obviously the earliest point of the object lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earliest point of the object lifecycle, yes, but not of the Android lifecycle. Most things will not yet have been initialized (e.g. the application context will only be set after `attachBaseContext()` was called)

Depending on what you plan on doing with Dagger (or your project in general) using the constructor *might* work, but I wouldn't be surprised if some things break.